# How can the \textmu symbol be used in math mode and resize correctly?

Tags: math-mode, boxes, greek

I wish to use an upright mu character in various places in my document, and so I've put the following in my preamble:

```
% textcomp, for its upright mu
\usepackage{textcomp}
% some user macros
\newcommand{\murm}{\hbox{\textmu}}
```

This is fine in both text and math mode, except when I try to place the mu in sub/superscript positions, and its size remains unchanged. Is there any way to resize it to fit its environment within math mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\mathchoice` to give four different definitions of the macro dependent if it is in display, in-text, script or scriptscript mode. (See also `\mathpalette`)

```
\newcommand{\murm}{%
    \mathchoice
        {\hbox{\normalsize\textmu}}
        {\hbox{\normalsize\textmu}}
        {\hbox{\scriptsize\textmu}}
        {\hbox{\tiny\textmu}}%
}
```

The whole expression should actually be wrapped into `\ensuremath` (`amsmath` package) or use `\ifmmode` manually to avoid errors if used in text-mode:

```
\newcommand{\murm}{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathchoice
        {\hbox{\normalsize\textmu}}
        {\hbox{\normalsize\textmu}}
        {\hbox{\scriptsize\textmu}}
        {\hbox{\tiny\textmu}}%
  \else
    \textmu
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use \ensuremath or similar to choose whether in math mode or not, and issue the \mathchoice command if so, and the regular command if not?

Comment: @Statto: Yes, like `\ensuremath` you can use `\ifmmode` to check if you are in mathmode: `\ifmmode \mathchoice ... (above code) \else \textmu \fi`

Comment: @Statto: You are welcome. Also note that you have now over 15rep points and are able to up-vote answers.

Comment: @Martin: The AMS `\text` macro does exactly this. `\newcommand*{\murm}{\text{\textmu}}` will do the right thing

Comment: @Danie Els: Ah, makes sense. I didn't know that `\text` also works in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `\upmu` from the [upgreek](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/upgreek) package? It will resize automatically in math mode.

Comment: Because the `\upmu` command doesn't render in the same font as the rest of the text. Since mu is the upright Greek character I'll be using most, it would be nice to get it right...